# Cropping an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop, biometrics

Is it possible to crop an image along a particular curve. for ex. I want to crop out the finger image out of this image, but i dont want to crop it along a rectangle. [image]

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of the curve along which you want to crop? If so, in which format?

Comment: You need to find an object of interest, make binary mask of it and multiply image on mask. Read about borders finding and filling.

Comment: you are aware that it will end up as a rectangle, because Matlab needs to represent the relevant points in some sort of a 2D array...

Comment: check roipoly which can form a polygonal binary mask. So you can approximate the curve by a polygon.

Answer (score 0):

you need a binary mask and apply that mask as alpha map
here is how it is usually done

```
s = 100;
h = imagesc(rand(s));%show some garbage

%prepare a circular mask
dummy = meshgrid(-s/2:s/2-1).^2;%squared distances from the center
mask =  sqrt(dummy+dummy') < 20;%20 is the radius of your mask

%here you go, mask the image in a curved manner
set(h,'alphaData',mask);
```

exporting it as a png would do the job.

so in your case, you need to make your own mask, this means either threshold your bitmap image  or parameterize the space (as I did it with the circle above).